# Vba doesn't recognize OLE object

Tags: vba, ms-office, excel-2010, ole

Hello all awesome programmers!

Can anyone explain to me how I fix this problem? 
It works great in excel 2003, but in 2010 i get this error:

[image: Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)']

Can someone guide me in the right direction?
What scaleheight is supposed to do, is making sure, that ALL the text copied into the word object is visible - which isn't the case if I set scaleheight to 1, but msoFalse.

You should be able to copy paste the code into a new sub.

```
Sub Embed_WordDocument_To_sheet()

Dim oWD As Document ' Word Document Object (Use Microsoft Word Reference)

Set ws = Worksheets.Add
Set wsFactark = Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("C3").Select

Set oOLEWd = ws.OLEObjects.Add( _
    ClassType:="Word.Document", _
    Width:=375)

oOLEWd.Name = "EmbeddedWordDoc"
oOLEWd.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
oOLEWd.Width = 375
oOLEWd.Height = 10 ' bliver ligegyldig når du har gjort det som står i nederste kommentar.
oOLEWd.Top = ws.Range("C3").Top + 2 ' +2 for ikke at overstrege border-linjen
oOLEWd.Left = ws.Range("C3").Left + 5 ' samme

' PROBLEM - "The relativetooriginalsize argument applies only to a picture or an OLE object." !!!
oOLEWd.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue ' msoFalse works, msoCTrue doesn't

oOLEWd.Placement = xlFreeFloating

' Assign the OLE Object to Word Object
Set oWD = oOLEWd.Object
wsFactark.Cells(I + 4, 13).Copy

oWD.Paragraphs(oWD.Paragraphs.Count).Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

With oWD.PageSetup
.TopMargin = 0
.BottomMargin = 0
.LeftMargin = 0
.RightMargin = 0
    .PageHeight = 1584 'max
    .PageWidth = 1584
End With

oOLEWd.Activate

oOLEWd.Height = selection.Application.UsableHeight

oOLEWd.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse

If oOLEWd.Height > 400 And oOLEWd.Height < 800 Then
    ws.Range("B3").RowHeight = 400
    ws.Range("B4").RowHeight = oOLEWd.Height - 400 + 20
ElseIf oOLEWd.Height > 800 And oOLEWd.Height < 1000 Then
    ws.Range("B3").RowHeight = 400
    ws.Range("B4").RowHeight = 200
    ws.Range("B5").RowHeight = 200
    ws.Range("B7").RowHeight = oOLEWd.Height - 800 + 20
ElseIf oOLEWd.Height > 1000 And oOLEWd.Height < 1200 Then
    ws.Range("B3").RowHeight = 400
    ws.Range("B4").RowHeight = 200
    ws.Range("B5").RowHeight = 200
    ws.Range("B6").RowHeight = 200
    ws.Range("B7").RowHeight = 200
    ws.Range("B9").RowHeight = oOLEWd.Height - 1000 + 20
Else
    ws.Range("B3").RowHeight = oOLEWd.Height
    ws.Range("B4:B11").RowHeight = 0
End If
    ws.Range("B12").RowHeight = 10

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of this line of code?  I haven't worked with this, but if you remove the line, the code works, and it seems to be trying to resize the object with a factor of 1 to its "original" size.  If this isn't really doing anything, I would just remove the line of code.

Comment: By "line of code" in the above comment, I mean "oOLEWd.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1, msoCTrue
"  Documentation on Microsoft's website suggests that you can't use msoCTrue in VBA, but I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: @OpiesDad No, you're right actually. I have tried with msoTrue as well without any results though. 

msoFalse works - which emphasizes the fact, that apparently my oOLEWd is not an OLE object. 
But why is that, and what can I do to make the scaleheight reach 1?

Comment: That method isn't setting the scale height to 1, it is actually scaling it by a factor of 1, which means it isn't doing anything. The state of True/False is referring to scaling the picture based on the ORIGINAL size of the object, not the current size of the object. The error may be incorrectly stating that it is not an OLE object, when really it means that the object can't store its ORIGINAL state. I'm not sure how to set the object to be able to store this state, though. I declared oOLEwd as an OLEObject and had the same error message.  Do you need it to resize to its original size?

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I need. 
I have tried to set the '1' to e.g. 1.1 or 2, it shows the same message.. 

You can get a better understanding of the problem if you stop the code  at the mistake, and then go into the format settings of the word object, into size and set the height to 100%. THAT'S what I need my code to do.! 

The silly thing is, that it works in excel 2003?

Comment: Is the setting different from 100% when you do this?  When I try to do this, the setting is already at 100%.

Comment: It works in excel 2007 too, but not in 2010 for me either.

Comment: Could you just save the height that it is originally and then set the height back to what it was originally?  I can't figure out why this won't work as written, but you could at least do that.  What's the purpose of changing the height and width and then changing it back 3 lines later?

Comment: Hey man - thanks for taking time to help me! :-)

the height on the object is variable. it depends on the 'I'.. It is only 100% if the copied text is small enough. Otherwise it is below 100% - meaning, that not all text is shown. This is a problem because in another place in the program I save the sheet as PDF. 

    `wsFactark.Cells(I + 4, 13).Copy`

Weird if it works in 2007, but not in 2010. :/

Comment: I tried adding the 2007 Word Reference library and this still doesn't work in 2010.  Not really sure what else to do.

Comment: Super weird!! Do you know where I could find help to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. If I get some more time I may try to mess around with it some more, but best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

this might do the trick (at least on my system - Excel 2010):

```
Sub M_snb()
  ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add , "G:\example.docx", True, False, , , , Columns(3).Left, Rows(3).Top
End Sub
```

to save the Word document as PDF:

```
Sub M_snb()
 Sheet1.Range("A1:G7").Copy

 With CreateObject("Word.document")
  .Windows(1).Visible = True
  .Content.Paste
  .ExportAsFixedFormat "G:\OF\new.pdf", 17
  .Close -1
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm.. Wouldnt this mean, that the document object already exists? 
Right now it isnt created until before the sub, and from the sub I copy the text into it..

Comment: As far as I can see you only want to copy 1 cell into the Word document. You can accomplish the exact same thing by opening an empty Word document with the code I showed and paste that cell into the newly created oleobject. Or: open the word document, paste the cell, save the Word document, open it in the excelfile as oleobject.

Comment: This sub is only part of my program. 
I have a table with a bunch of information concerning how to work with a construction project. There is an increasing amount of 'recipes' that explains specific things about the project.
In the table each row is a recipe, and the columns are the how's, why's, when, notes etc.
My program takes the information of each row and puts it in a new sheet. Then it prints it as a pdf and takes the next row. 

It's the 'how'-column that is causing me some trouble.. The text length is variable, therefore the Object height also needs to be variable.

Comment: I get confused: do you want a Word document ?, A PDF-file ? or a Worddocument as OleObject in the worksheet ? I added some code how to save the copied range in a Word document as PDF-file.

Comment: I understand why you're confused. I want a word-object in the excel spreadsheet, which shall be saved as pdf. 
I have a table from where each row will be put out as a pdf.. Each row consists of hows, whens, wheres etc for a building project. I need this so I can update it one place instead of 8 different places.

Comment: I think my last code suggestion does exactly that. The introduction of a Word oleobject in Excel is an unnecessary complicated method.

Comment: Wonderful! I'll try it out next time I'm at work and see where it's get me..
I'll be sure to make an update in here..